# How to turn monitor off/on programmatically when using Wayland?

Tags: multiple-monitors, display, xrandr, wayland

I have a scripted routine for turning off screens for gaming (some older games don't like multiple screens) with `xrandr`, for example `xrandr --output DVI-D-0 --off`. Wenn using Wayland (by selecting it during login and confirming `XDG_SESSION_TYPE=wayland` in `env`) the numbers are 1 off and the command fails due to

```
$ xrandr --output DVI-D-1 --off
X Error of failed request:  BadMatch (invalid parameter attributes)
  Major opcode of failed request:  139 (RANDR)
  Minor opcode of failed request:  7 (RRSetScreenSize)
  Serial number of failed request:  27
  Current serial number in output stream:  29
```

I'm guess that's because `xrandr` is an X server tool doesn't work with Wayland, but that's just a guess.

Which equivalent command can I use to turn off a monitor programmatically with Wayland? The monitors I'd like to control are connected with DVI and HDMI in case that matters.

I'm using Ubuntu 23.10.

Comment: try "xset -display :0.0 dpms force off"

Comment: @petep fails due to `server does not have extension for dpms option`. I guess "xset ‐ user preference utility for X" (according to `man xset`) has the same troubles as `xrandr` on Wayland.